# Redirect a product to other website

Tags: magento

I am looking for a way to have a product on my magento store, make it visible but not purchaseable and redirect users accessing it to another page/external url.
Basically i have 6 products and would like to redirect all users who go to one of those products to another domain / external url. The product should be displayed but not be purchaseable - rather instead of add to cart link to an external url - or if possible even redirect the whole product detail page to another url...

What’d be the best way to do that?

i am trying for two days already but haven’t found the best solution yet… my programming skills aren't the best yet...

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think what you should do is to add one new attribute for redirect url , for your six products you can specify the redirect  url in that attribute , and in the list.phtml you can place a condition that if a product has value in that attribute , you can use that value in anchor tag and in else case you cam use the regular product links for other products .

Comment: hmm ok that's an interesting, but too complex answer for me... can you specify how to add an attribute in redirect url? I also don't understand the second half of the sentence... hmm...

Answer (score 0):

i mean you can add a new attribute for a products in admin like there is other attributes eg. name, description , and in file you can fetch your new attribute like other attributes , just replace the attribute code with your  and take that in condition that it will work work only if the product has the value for your new attribute

for fetching attribute in your file you can use    `<?php echo $_product->getAttributeName() ?>`